# Swift 4.1 Parse Portion of JSON

Tags: json, swift, parsing, decodable

I'm fairly recent to Swift and would like to take advantage of the Decodable functionalities, was hoping for some help.

A public API I am consuming emits the data I want under the key: 'c' but there is some metadata surrounding it. For example:

```
{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: [{
      d: 3,
      e: 4
    },
    {
      d: 5,
      e: 6
    }
  ]
}
```

I've created a struct like this:

```
struct Block: Decodable {
   d: Int?
   e: Int?
}
```

As above, I'd like to be able to have the data parsed into type: `[Block]` from the data under 'c' as *swiftly* (sorry) as possible and was hoping there is a 4.1 way of accomplishing this.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: So you want to omit a: 1, b: 2?

Comment: @PiotrLabunski yes exactly. I'm just wondering the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest (*most swiftly*) way is just to create two structs

```
struct BlockResponse: Decodable {
  let c: [Block]
}

struct Block: Decodable {
  let d: Int?
  let e: Int?
}
```

and then

```
let result = try decoder.decode(BlockResponse.self, from: jsonResponse)
```

**EDIT:**
You can also omit `BlockResponse` like here
https://gist.github.com/sgr-ksmt/d3b79ed1504768f2058c5ea06dc93698

by using the extension with keyPath:

```
extension JSONDecoder {
  func decode<T: Decodable>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data, keyPath: String) throws -> T {
      let toplevel = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
      if let nestedJson = (toplevel as AnyObject).value(forKeyPath: keyPath) {
          let nestedJsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: nestedJson)
          return try decode(type, from: nestedJsonData)
      } else {
          throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Nested json not found for key path \"\(keyPath)\""))
      }
  }
}



try decoder.decode([Block].self, from: data, keyPath: "c")
```

Comment: Thank you, I was under the impression that structs had to match the json format identically, didn't know you could omit fields!

Comment: Is this *really* the easiest way to do it?  A lot of languages make this feet pretty easy.  Why should I create unnecessary wrappers to hold my business data just in order to conform to the API even though I'll never consume or have a use for that hierarchy in the application code.....  it adds waste and unneeded complexity to your project.  It seems that Swift will make you go through these hurdles....

Comment: You can use the version with keyPath without additional structures (see Edit). In my opinion, you should not send unnecessary data to your mobile client at all. If API is not controlled by you, you can create a middleware to adjust data for the mobile client.